# Sending HTML to backend

Tags: java, html

I'm trying to send some rendered HTML to the backend, through ajax, using javascript or jquery, but I can't find the way to do it.

I'm trying to export that html to pdf using itext.

Is there any way that I can achieve this, sending the data as a String?.

Many thanks.

(I'm using Java and Spring on the backend)

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: Post the HTML as a JSON object?

Comment: @magnudae I'd like to have it as a String, as I'm trying to export that html to pdf using itext.

Comment: so whats the problem? did you even try solving this on your own?

Comment: Yeah. If you wrap it in JSON objects you can still access it as a string. I think the answer below is a correct approach to this issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send you HTML as a JSON object. Here a quick example.

```
    var elm = document.getElementById('yourElement');
    var value = elm.innerHTML;
    var objToSend = JSON.stringify(value);
// now send using ajax
...
```

Comment: Please note: be careful to security, especially Cross-site scripting (XSS) when sending HTML (special User generated content) to the server.